# Semantic Version comparison and labelling without packages

Tags: python, pandas, versioning, semantic-versioning

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
api_spec_id label    info_version   commitDate
    803            2.3.0            2019-09-12
    803            2.4.1            2019-10-04
    803            2.4.2            2019-10-07
    803            2.5.3            2019-10-08
    803            2.6.1            2019-10-08
    803            2.6.3            2019-11-25
    803            2.6.5            2019-12-10
    803            2.6.6            2019-12-11
    803            2.7.2            2019-12-11
    803            2.8.0            2019-12-19
```

The `packaging.Version` class sorts them into basic labels of `major`, `minor` etc, but the case in my dataset is a bit different since sometimes versions upgrade can be like `2.5.3` to `2.6.1`, so here we have `Minor.Patch` changing at the same time, I do not want to give then only one label since that hinders my analysis and leads to bias. We also have cases where versions go from `2.3.0` to `2.4.1` where the upgrade pattern is `Major.Minor` and lastly for `Major.Patch` in the same way. The dataset has such odd conventions since it is crawled from real api data.

Apart from this, we also have cases where `major.minor.patch` are all equal, and we have pre identifiers like `alpha,beta,rc,dev,pre`. In such cases I want to compare them according to the standard `alpha < beta < rc < pre < dev`. In exception cases where this identifier is same as well, I want to compare the number afterwards. There are cases of the form `1.2.6.7`, which I am think can be in the same category of major.minor.patch.micro( micro here being the 4th number).

The expected output should be like this:

```
api_spec_id label    info_version           commitDate
    803      -              2.3.0                 2019-09-12
    803    minor.patch      2.4.1                 2019-10-04
    803    patch            2.4.2                 2019-10-07
    803    minor.patch      2.5.3                 2019-10-08
    803    minor.patch      2.6.1                 2019-10-08
    803    patch            2.6.3                 2019-11-25
    803    patch            2.6.5                 2019-12-10
    803    patch            2.6.6                 2019-12-11
    803    minor.patch      2.7.2                 2019-12-11
    803    major            2.8.0                 2019-12-19
    803    pre              2.8.0a1               2019-12-24
    803    pre              2.8.0a2               2019-12-27
    803    pre              2.9.0.dev             2021-01-03
    803    micro            2.9.0.2               2021-01-10
    803    no change        2.9.0.2               2021-01-15
```

I parsed all these versions and they are in canonical format according to PEP440 regex, but I am not sure  how to compare between these, because a regex won't work here, so I am in a bit of fix. Does anyone have ideas/suggestions on how to tackle this?

Comment: Can you update your example with a pre-version and a micro version, please?

Comment: I updated the dataframe with examples of pre and micro versioning schemes!

Comment: I also added a case where the version remains same: `no change`

Comment: Hey, if you could assist me on the regex for pre and no change it would be great! I am trying to modify the regex but it keeps giving me the wrong output.

Comment: I'll try to modify it. Do you want to use the overcomplicated regex from PEP ?

Comment: I think so I might have too, since these API versions are very odd, I think this would be the best possible way forward

Comment: Is it possible for you to install external package to handling versions? (possibly already installed)

Comment: Yess that would be possible since all the version packages are already installed,as i was trying the parsing before this. Then I had to separate out the outliers as I mentioned in the comment below, since those versions don't follow any given format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 1**

As second step, you can use `packaging` package from pypi's team:

```
# pip install packaging
from packaging.version import Version, parse

attrs = ['major', 'micro', 'minor', 'pre', 'post', 'dev', 'local']
def extract_version(ver):
    ver = parse(ver)  # or Version(ver)
    return pd.Series({attr: getattr(ver, attr) for attr in attrs}, dtype=str)

sem = df['info_version'].agg(extract_version).fillna('').rename(columns={'minor': 'patch'})
diff = sem.ne(sem.shift().fillna(sem.iloc[0]))
df['label'] = diff.dot(sem.columns + '.').str.rstrip('.')
```

Output

```
    api_spec_id info_version  commitDate          label
0           803        2.3.0  2019-09-12               
1           803        2.4.1  2019-10-04    micro.minor
2           803        2.4.2  2019-10-07          micro
3           803        2.5.3  2019-10-08    micro.minor
4           803        2.6.1  2019-10-08    micro.minor
5           803        2.6.3  2019-11-25          micro
6           803        2.6.5  2019-12-10          micro
7           803        2.6.6  2019-12-11          micro
8           803        2.7.2  2019-12-11    micro.minor
9           803        2.8.0  2019-12-19    micro.minor
10          803      2.8.0a1  2019-12-24            pre
11          803      2.8.0a2  2019-12-27            pre
12          803    2.9.0.dev  2021-01-03  minor.pre.dev
13          803      2.9.0.2  2021-01-10            dev
14          803      2.9.0.2  2021-01-15
```

Other output:

```
>>> sem
   major micro patch       pre post dev local
0      2     0     3                         
1      2     1     4                         
2      2     2     4                         
3      2     3     5                         
4      2     1     6                         
5      2     3     6                         
6      2     5     6                         
7      2     6     6                         
8      2     2     7                         
9      2     0     8                         
10     2     0     8  ('a', 1)               
11     2     0     8  ('a', 2)               
12     2     0     9                  0      
13     2     0     9                         
14     2     0     9                         

>>> diff
    major  micro  patch    pre   post    dev  local
0   False  False  False  False  False  False  False
1   False   True   True  False  False  False  False
2   False   True  False  False  False  False  False
3   False   True   True  False  False  False  False
4   False   True   True  False  False  False  False
5   False   True  False  False  False  False  False
6   False   True  False  False  False  False  False
7   False   True  False  False  False  False  False
8   False   True   True  False  False  False  False
9   False   True   True  False  False  False  False
10  False  False  False   True  False  False  False
11  False  False  False   True  False  False  False
12  False  False   True   True  False   True  False
13  False  False  False  False  False   True  False
14  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
```

---

**Original answer**

As starting point, you can use (assuming dataframe is sorted by `commitDate`):

```
# Simple regex pattern (subset of PEP440)
pat = r'(?P<major>\d+)\.(?P<minor>\d+)\.(?P<patch>\d+)(?:\.(?P<micro>\d+))?'

# Extract component version
sem = df['info_version'].str.extract(pat).fillna(0).astype(int)

# Check the difference
diff = sem.diff().fillna(0).ne(0)

# Use dot product
df['label'] = diff.dot(sem.columns + '.').str.rstrip('.')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  api_spec_id info_version commitDate        label
0         803        2.3.0 2019-09-12             
1         803        2.4.1 2019-10-04  minor.patch
2         803        2.4.2 2019-10-07        patch
3         803        2.5.3 2019-10-08  minor.patch
4         803        2.6.1 2019-10-08  minor.patch
5         803        2.6.3 2019-11-25        patch
6         803        2.6.5 2019-12-10        patch
7         803        2.6.6 2019-12-11        patch
8         803        2.7.2 2019-12-11  minor.patch
9         803        2.8.0 2019-12-19  minor.patch
```

Other output:

```
>>> sem
   major  minor  patch  micro
0      2      3      0      0
1      2      4      1      0
2      2      4      2      0
3      2      5      3      0
4      2      6      1      0
5      2      6      3      0
6      2      6      5      0
7      2      6      6      0
8      2      7      2      0
9      2      8      0      0

>>> diff
   major  minor  patch  micro
0  False  False  False  False
1  False   True   True  False
2  False  False   True  False
3  False   True   True  False
4  False   True   True  False
5  False  False   True  False
6  False  False   True  False
7  False  False   True  False
8  False   True   True  False
9  False   True   True  False
```

**Note**: it doesn't solve pre-version for the moment but the regex pattern can be modified.

Comment: How will the modification for `pre` and `micro` be? Also, I had a doubt, so these versions cleared the standardized regex, but quite a few of them failed, versions like `v1.2`, `v1.0.0beta`, `2.0.0-alpha1`, `2.000-SNAPSHOT`, or just words like `beta, alpha,stable,dev,latest..`, or even `2018-11-14T00:00:00.000Z` years like this. Is there a way I could use a package and get the same output as the one I mentioned for such outliers as well? Since I am not sure how complicated the regex will get.

Comment: @BrieMerryWeather. I updated my answer. Can you check it please? I reuse PEP440 regex with `packaging` module.

Comment: I checked the edits, it worked perfectly, this was very useful, thank you so much for the answer! I just had 2 doubts, the one i mentioned in the previous comment about the outlier versions and second was that in the edited code: `micro` represents patch and `minor` represents `micro`? I think I got a bit confused there.

Comment: From PEP440: *The “Major.Minor.Patch” (described in this PEP as “major.minor.micro”)* Patch and micro are the same thing

Comment: This "2.9.0.2" is not PEP440 compliant, you are right.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that for the other non-compliant versions, will those be possible with a regex?Although few are parsable by `Version` class, some however are not.

Comment: Maybe you can post another question with non compliant versions? I'm not very good with regex :-(

Comment: I apologize for the late response, I got into some issues with my laptop, however I posted a question detailing info on the non-compliant versions.

Comment: By the way I realized a flaw with the answer, when it extracts the pat, it considers every info_version and hence for some cases if there is a number at the top, it is getting labelled. The first row for some of the api's don't have an empty string, since due to the diff being calculated, it is comparing values in some cases

Comment: This case is PEP440 compliant?

Comment: yes it is actually a semantic version

Comment: Do you know how could i fix this?

Comment: Can you give me an example please (info_version, expected label and label you get)?

Comment: This occurrence I found to be present for quite some of the api's where the first row was something like this:` info_version`:1.0.0, `label`:major.minor.patch`

The expected label for the first row for all `api_spec_id` first `commit_date` should be zero, because there is no previous row to compare the label with. I found these cases during my analysis.

Comment: I think it's because there is no groupby in my answer because you have only one api_spec_id in your example.

Comment: Ahh yess that could be a possible reason

Comment: I tried doing a groupby however i get the same result, the error remains.

Comment: Even if the diff between the previous rows is all False, like the first and second one, it still assigns them a label

Comment: Can you share a csv file with an example or a Google Colab?

Comment: The issue actually comes when doing on the entire dataset, if we try on individual id's by putting them into a seperate df, then it works.If you want I could send you the file, i have been thinking about a different way now to tackle this

Comment: hey, I made another question with my issue, it would be really great if you could help me figure out where I am going wrong.

Comment: This is not the first time you've unchecked my accepted answer. I don't understand the reason. I can help you but stop doing this to get my attention, it's not very fair. This answer solved your current question. I already spend too much time on StackOverflow answering questions and more than chatting with people.

Comment: @BrieMerryWeather. I answered to your new question

Comment: I removed the accepted answer as I was planning to start a bounty on this question after modifying it, and deleting the new question I had posted, this was in no attempt to catch your attention or anything, neither am I an experienced user of Stack Overflow. I found an answer to my solution, so I will be deleting my new question anyways. Apologies, and no one is obliged to answer my questions or doubts, it's upto the user to decide whether or not they would like to pursue it further. I hope it's all clear now, and you don't have to answer my question anymore. Thanks alot.

Comment: I apologise if in this any way affected your reputation, which was not my attention, and I thank you for all your insights you have always provided, they have been of good assistance to me

Comment: Since you already answered, I will accept it, thanks alot and I won't be deleting it now, I do not wish for your efforts to go waste in any way.

Comment: Have a nice day as well.